# Why put search input inside a form tag?

Tags: html, search

I found that SO put the search input inside a form tag, and i found some other websites do the same, such as google, they put the search input and search button inside this:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" name="gs" id="tsf">
```

I want to just know the benefits of doing so, because it seems common and I miss it.

Comment: I dont know why this question was downvoted... It may be simple but it is programming related and legitimate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about you read a [tutorial on HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)?

The data entered in the form must be send to a server. The `action` attribute tells the browser *which* server.

Also, there are two common ways to send the data: through `POST` (in the [`HTTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) header) and through `GET` (as part of the query string, the part after the question mark in a `URL`). Which method must be used is specified in the `method` attribute.

`POST` is commonly used when data should be submitted only once or should be private (e.g. registering at or logging in to a site). `GET` is used for data that may be send as often as necessary (because the resulting `URL` contains a query string that one can e.g. bookmark). Example: Google search queries are sent using `GET`, but to log in to your GMail account `POST` is used. A more elaborate explanation can be found [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html).

**Edit**: below you ask why the whole page can't just be wrapped in one form tag. As [divo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/divo) correctly answers: you may have multiple forms that can be submitted to different servers. For example, you can provide two text fields on your webpage: one that allows one to search the site using Google, the other using Yahoo. With a little creativity other uses will come to mind.

**Edit 2**:

> Can you point to a different tutorial?
>   W3Schools has errors. – [David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward)
>   10 mins ago

If that is so (I didn't check), these two look promising:

- [tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php)
- [javascript-coder.com](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml)

Answer (score 4):

The `action` attribute of the `<form>` element tells the browser which URL on the server is responsible for handling the form.

Answer (score 0):

How else would you transmit the search term to the server?  The reason the input in inside a form tag is so that the browser can POST the value to the server for processing.

**Edit:** In order to understand better I would suggest that you read [HTML Forms and Input](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Comment: This would be most common of course, but it is *possible* to do it other ways.. parameter to search Url for example..

Comment: The form's action attribute defines the name of the file to send the content to. The file defined in the action attribute usually does something with the received input.

Comment: The action attribute specifies the URL to sent the data to, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

The search input is just a generic text box, and the only way to get the information (what you're searching for) from the page to the server is to send it via a form.

www.w3schools.com and others have some great tutorials on building forms.

Theoretically you can use JavaScript to submit the information without explicitly typing out a form, but if the client has JavaScript disabled, it will never work - whereas using the HTML  will work all the time

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a stretch, but based on your website www.igurr.com, I think what you're really asking is:

> Why don't I have to put a form tag on my page to get it to post back?

This is because ASP.NET automatically adds a `form` tag for you right after the `body` tag:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the reason, which is very simple:

instead of putting a big general form tag for all the page, these websites just put form around the parts which will go back to the server, but why not put everything inside a form, that what i am trying to understand now.

Comment: Simply because you might want to have several multiple forms with different actions on a single page.

Comment: Because the whole page isn't a form. Same reason you don't put the whole page inside a table or a p tag.